Ensure concurrent processing based on a message key
I've been wondering about the following: Say you have an async message/task and you want that message only processed one at the time. for example: Only process one order for each customer at the time. They do not have to per se have to be in order of publishing the message, but most important part is that it is asynchronously and it wont start processing a second message from the same customer until the first one is finished.
I've tried to find a datastructure or architecture that allows this but so far i haven't found a simple solution.
What i've found is:

Something called message affinity. But it is strongly discouraged from using.
Make a queue per "Customer" and somehow ensure there is always maximal 1 consumer per queue. (haven't found a good solution for this that works/scales well).
Use a distributed locking system and try to acquire a lock before starting to process the message otherwise not acknowledge/delay that message and proces a next one.

None of these solutions seem particularly efficient. Is there an efficient solution
Note: Im currently using Redis Queue system but I'm more interested in if there is a general solution than if Redis has a solution.

I'm not sure about a general solution, but using Kafka would (almost) automatically give you this property.
Messages in Kafka already have a "key", which is used to distribute messages to multiple nodes if it needs be. In your case, the key would be the customer id for example. This would guarantee that even if the consumers scale (for the same group*), messages for the same customer would always go to the same instance, essentially giving you a sequential, non-parallel processing for all customers.
Be aware, that if there is a re-balancing, i.e. nodes going down or up, it could happen that the customer is "transferred" to a different node. So, you would potentially have to deal with that. However, you'll be notified of this, so you can handle it.
So this is something you would get essentially "for free" using Kafka. However, I obviously don't know how the rest of your requirements would fare. And also, there's quite a lot of things you'll need to know to operate Kafka, if you're not getting it as a service.

Your approach could be explicit or implicit.
In the explicit approach, associate the target message consumer in the design. Sometimes this is the right approach. Rather more up-front design cost.
In the implicit approach, hash on the source identity to chose the consumer. A good hash function will spread a large number of sources evenly across consumers, and ensure messages from one source are processed by one consumer, in sequence.
Small numbers of very-different sources might favor the explicit model. Large numbers of sources tends to favor the implicit model (with perhaps biased hash).

I've found this term is called Message "grouping".
Implementations that i have found:

Amazon SQS Group ID: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html
Azure Service bus queue sessions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions.
Rabbit MQ discusses this topic: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/4975
Redis: doesnt seem to have it in default queue system: https://redis.io/glossary/redis-queue/ but Redis Streams seems to support this feature: https://redis.io/blog/youre-probably-thinking-about-redis-streams-wrong/



Only process one order for each customer at the time. They do not have to per se have to be in order of publishing the message, but most important part is that it is asynchronously and it wont start processing a second message from the same customer until the first one is finished.

Why?
I'm not just being awkward - the reason matters. If processing an order involves interacting with the database, there are two approaches that would work:

put the whole processing in a single database transaction. You may have to set DB isolation to "repeatable read" or "serializable" to do this correctly.

explicitly lock the customer account for processing. That is, have a column which contains either "0" to indicate "not in use", or a number indicating which system is currently processing that account. You then need a mechanism for re-queuing with a delay when there is contention for an account. You still need to think about transactionality, but may be able to set the DB to a lower serialization level.


(recording which system/process/thread is currently doing the processing is necessary for automatic crash recovery; if you have recorded that process 1234 is working on it, and 1234 has crashed and is no longer in the process table, you should zero out that field, effectively aborting the transaction).
